# Couldnt connect to ec2 instance through git bash

Tags: git-bash

I have the error:

```bash
ssh -i "D:\LINUX\LINUXKEY.pem" ec2-user@172..xx.xxx
Warning: Identity file D:\LINUX\LINUXKEY.pem not accessible: No such file or directory.
```

I have tried different paths, and still the same warning.

Also: `chmod 400 path/file.pem`

Comment: In git-bash the path must be linux-style. Check the file is accessible using `ls /d/LINUX/LINUXKEY.pem`

Answer (score 1):

I just checked with a git bash session on Windows: a simple ls is able to use a Windows-style path (between double-quotes), and is case insensitive.

So check first if a simple `ls "D:\LINUX\LINUXKEY.pem"` works.

Or at least try and `cd` to that folder. It would translate it in `/d/LINUX`.
Then a `ssh -i "LINUXKEY.pem" ec2-user@172.xx.xxx` would be simpler.